# placeholder image is displaying in place of first image while loading dynamic image in crystal report

Tags: visual-studio-2010, crystal-reports

I am trying to insert the images in one of my crystal sub reports. I have tried the following steps:

1. Insert a placeholder image.
2. right-click the graphic -> 'Format Graphic' -> 'Picture' tab -> Add a formula under 'Graphic Location'(basically given path of the images from the table).
3. Run the report.

I  all my images get loaded as expected except for the first one. In place of first image, the place holder image is displaying only (which is undesired). I am unable to understand where I am committing a mistake. I am new in crystal report any help this regards will highly appreciated. I am basically developing a Windows application with Visual Studio 2010 and I have CR runtime version CR13_3_0_3.

Answer (score 0):

There may be a number of causes for this problem.
Please try to do the following:

1. Right-click the graphic -> 'Format Graphic' -> 'Common' tab -> Make sure "Can Grow" is ticked and "Lock Position And Size" is unticked.
2. Try enlarging the section size so the picture could fit.
3. Make sure whether the formula that brings the picture from the table is 0-based or not. 
   You can try switching between a picture that does show and the one that doesn't in order to understand whether the problem occurs due to the picture itself or is it something with your report configuration.

Comment: Hi Urik, 
 Lot Thanks to help me.I tried with all the given suggestions but it did not work for me and still place holder image comes in place of first image and rest image renders good. When I preview report from "PreviewMainReport" option in crystal report it works fine with as per my current implementation  i.e all expected images display (no placeholder image comes in report).But if I open the same report on button click from app then I find the issue. I think(not sure as i have not much idea) that my first image gets replaced by place holder image later on in report generation life cycle.

Comment: I think that the difference between the preview in CR and the report you see when running the app is because of a different .dll are being used. I would suggest to check if the problem is in a specific image or a general one, i.e. replace the first image that isn't showing with one that is shown on page 2 for example. Another thing to check is in the "section expert". Make sure that no checkbox is ticked there, for the specific section except for the checkbox "Keep Together". Maybe there, the surpress is being activated.

Comment: Hi Urik, Issue is generic one and it comes for the first image only.No checkbox  other than "Keep Together" is  checked.I tried lot more permutation combinaion but could not able to resolve it so far.

Comment: At this point, I would suggest to try and create a new, clean crystal report and insert only the image placeholder. Then, try to connect the button to this report and see if it works. You need to understand the source for the problem. I'm thinking that maybe the report header at the first page is interrupting...

Comment: Hi Urik, I tried with new test report and it worked fine.Also I tried with sub report as it was in my case it worked. In the investigation I found issue occured only when I set parameter from main report to subreport. I saw the sql query of my sub report which have simple select statement with 4 columns only and parameter coming from mainreport to subreport filters the only data in sub report which have relevency with mainreport.

Comment: As before, try proceeding with the clean report that has the subreport working with the image placeholder. Take another step further and try to pass to it the parameter and use it to query ONLY for the data needed for the placeholder. If this doesn't work, try passing the data directly. Since it works well with a new report, it has to do with something specific with your original report (probably either query syntax or formation, parameters passing and so on...)

Comment: Hi Urik, Finally I resolved  my issue after opting alterantive root of wrting image through stream object in my report. Intrestingly my previous approch was running well in few machines but in inconsistent way, but sream approach worked in all machine. Again thanking you to being so helpful.